# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView : make horizontal scroll easier to do

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

I'm developping a Android app, and I got a vertical NestedScrollView, who take all my screen, and inside multiple hoizontal RecyclerView. It's work, but the horizontal scroll is really hard to achieve.

I mean, when I scroll horizontally the gesture is catch by the NestedScrollView, and the view move up/down. I need to focus and do a real horizontal movement to scroll the RecyclerView, it's killing UX...

Here my NestedScrollView :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I'm inflating RecyclerView programmatically, because the number is define in network data, here the inflated layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="@dimen/secondary_text_size"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/recycler_view_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And how I set my RecyclerView in Java :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_layout, null, false);

RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(this);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

I tried to change the "velocity" NestedScrollView, but I can't find good advice/post, maybe I don't find the good one. Someone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you find it useful, as I think you need to implement one of these libraries (on GitHub you would find more):

- View Flow for Android: https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow
- HorizontalListView:  https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView
- TwoWayGridView https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

---

If you want to do it with standard Android libraries, `RecyclerView` might be useful if you want to scroll horizontally

To prove that it has horizontally scrolling support, take a look at:

> **public boolean canScrollHorizontally ()**
>
> Query if horizontal scrolling is currently supported. The default
>   implementation returns false.
>
> **Returns** True if this LayoutManager can scroll the current contents horizontally

or

> **public int computeHorizontalScrollExtent (RecyclerView.State state)**
>
> Override this method if you want to support scroll bars.
>
> Read computeHorizontalScrollExtent() for details.
>
> Default implementation returns 0.
>
> From: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html

Check also subclass of [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) called [`HorizontalGridView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/HorizontalGridView.html)

Hope it help.